# Rust function does not have static lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to make this simple code compile:

```
fn dox(x: u8) -> u8 { x*2 }

fn main() {
    let cb: &'static (Fn(u8) -> u8) = &dox;
}
```

But it fails with Rust 1.9:

```
x.rs:4:40: 4:43 error: borrowed value does not live long enough
x.rs:4     let cb: &'static (Fn(u8) -> u8) = &dox;
                                              ^~~
note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
x.rs:4:44: 5:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 4:43
x.rs:4     let cb: &'static (Fn(u8) -> u8) = &dox;
x.rs:5 }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How is it possible that a free function does not have static lifetime? How could this code be unsafe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Rust 1.21, "static promotion" is performed automatically and your original code compiles as-is.

This code compiles as well:

```
fn main() {
    let a: &'static i32 = &5;
}
```

Additionally, closures which do not capture anything from their environment can be automatically converted to function pointers, so you don't need to create a separate function, either:

```
fn main() {
    let cb: fn(u8) -> u8 = |x| x * 2;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The type of `&dox` is not `&Fn(u8) -> u8` (or even `&fn(u8) -> u8`), it is merely *coercible to* `&Fn(u8) -> u8`. Therefore, you're actually taking the address of a temporary. Temporaries aren't promoted to `'static` lifetime even if they could, in principle, be `'static`. For example this code doesn't work either:

```
fn main() {
    let a: &'static i32 = &5;
}
```

There are some workarounds for this. Normally one can just explicitly create a `static` variable and take the reference to that:

```
fn main() {
    static FIVE: i32 = 5;
    let a: &'static i32 = &FIVE;
}
```

In your specific case that doesn't work directly because `Fn(u8) -> u8` is an unsized type (a trait, specifically) so you can't just put that in a `static`. You can do this:

```
fn main() {
    static DOX: fn(u8) -> u8 = dox; // note: fn, not Fn
    let a: &'static Fn(u8) -> u8 = &DOX;
}
```

However, a static reference to a `Fn*` trait object is a rather silly thing. Closures which can be `'static` references are extremely rare, so you might just as well use a plain `fn(u8) -> u8` type and sidestep the whole lifetime business.