# How to create a lazy_static HashMap with function references as value?

Tags: rust

I tried to create a `HashMap` with functions as the values:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::collections::HashMap;

lazy_static! {
    static ref HASHES: HashMap<&'static str, &'static Fn([u8])> = {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("md5", &md5);
        m
    };
}

fn md5(bytes: &[u8]) -> String {
    String::default()
}
```

The compiler gives me an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::ops::Fn([u8]) + 'static: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied in `&'static std::ops::Fn([u8]) + 'static`
  --> src/main.rs:6:1
   |
6  |   lazy_static! {
   |  _^ starting here...
7  | |     static ref HASHES: HashMap<&'static str, &'static Fn([u8])> = {
8  | |         let mut m = HashMap::new();
9  | |         m.insert("md5", &md5);
10 | |         m
11 | |     };
12 | | }
   | |_^ ...ending here: within `&'static std::ops::Fn([u8]) + 'static`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `std::ops::Fn([u8]) + 'static`
   |
   = note: `std::ops::Fn([u8]) + 'static` cannot be shared between threads safely
   = note: required because it appears within the type `&'static std::ops::Fn([u8]) + 'static`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Sync` for `std::collections::hash::table::RawTable<&'static str, &'static std::ops::Fn([u8]) + 'static>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::collections::HashMap<&'static str, &'static std::ops::Fn([u8]) + 'static>`
   = note: required by `lazy_static::lazy::Lazy`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

I don't understand what should I do to fix this error and I don't know any other way of creating such a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues. The error presented by the compiler is telling you that your code, will allow memory unsafety:

```
`std::ops::Fn([u8]) + 'static` cannot be shared between threads safely
```

The type you are storing in your `HashMap` has no guarantee that it can be shared.

You can "fix" that by specifying such a bound by changing your value type to `&'static (Fn([u8]) + Sync)`. This unlocks the next error, due to the fact that your function signatures don't match up:

```
expected type `std::collections::HashMap<&'static str, &'static std::ops::Fn([u8]) + std::marker::Sync + 'static>`
   found type `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &fn(&[u8]) -> std::string::String {md5}>`
```

"Fixing" that with `&'static (Fn(&[u8]) -> String + Sync)` leads to esoteric higher-kinded lifetime errors:

```
expected type `std::collections::HashMap<&'static str, &'static for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r [u8]) -> std::string::String + std::marker::Sync + 'static>`
   found type `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &fn(&[u8]) -> std::string::String {md5}>`
```

Which can be "fixed" by casting the function with `&md5 as &'static (Fn(&[u8]) -> String + Sync))`, which leads to

```
note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

This bottoms out because [the reference you've made is to a temporary value that doesn't live outside of the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043201/155423).

---

I put fix in scare quotes because this isn't really the right solution. The right thing is to just use a function pointer:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref HASHES: HashMap<&'static str, fn(&[u8]) -> String> = {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("md5", md5 as fn(&[u8]) -> std::string::String);
        m
    };
}
```

Honestly, I'd say that a `HashMap` is probably overkill; I'd use an array. A small array is probably faster than a small `HashMap`:

```
type HashFn = fn(&[u8]) -> String;

static HASHES: &'static [(&'static str, HashFn)] = &[
    ("md5", md5),
];
```

You can start by just iterating through the list, or maybe be fancy and alphabetize it and then use [`binary_search`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search) when it gets a bit bigger.

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb to decide between a HashMap and an array of two-tuples? Is it dependent on the collection size? And/or whether we know the size in advance?

Comment: @ArmandoPérezMarqués I always recommend benchmarking if it's important. You certainly would need to know the size in advance to create an *array*, but beyond that I'd say it's "a slice of 2-tuples is OK for a 'small' number of values".